# tesseract not reading text and number which has background image using java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I tried to read image using tess4j(1.1) for tesseract but unable to read those numbers/chars which has background image,so I applied thresholding on image and image change to black and white but also the problem remains same.

So I want to know that,

> is it possible by using tess4j(tesserarct) to read characters/numbers which has background color or image in background.
>   If it is possible then try to provide some clues for it.
>
> OR
>
> is it possible to get result by making some changes in traineddata for character recognition

For such scenarios,is javacv  the only option available and not tesseract?

I am also finding opportunity with neural network but it seems to require more time for it.

Is any solution for it?

Using tess4j example is

```
File imageFile = new File("myimage.jpg");

Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();

String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your image?

Comment: hi, you can check image here                         >http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rNbn4r1p2lE/UCUdqjlJU4I/AAAAAAAALdk/6GyWaINdKp4/s1600/Citibank+Rewards+Card.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract is not the best way for image processing.

There are other better options available like Neural Network,Template matching and other.

In any case,it is needed to clean the image background so have the option of javacv for image background cleaning.

And also until now tesseract not able to identify numbers.So I think that Neural Network is the good option for image text reading and using that I am able to get around 60%+ accuracy result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Jumio Netswipe SDK to read credit cards http://jumio.com/products/netswipe/overview/

Comment: It's good,but condition is that I want to find solution which is opensource.

Comment: Don't think you'll find a solution to such a specialized and complex problem open source - maybe you'll and I'm wrong ;)